# Selenium WebDriver - Way to change firefox file save location

Tags: webdriver

Is there a way to change the location where firefox saves downloaded files using selenium webdriver?

Anyone have selenium web driver code to change the location where firefox saves the downloaded files?

Answer (score 2):

if you know how to use Firefox profiles with custom preferences, 
then the setting you are looking is  "browser.download.dir"

```
fProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", @your_dir);
```

have look at more Firefox download options and other configs @ http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries